# How to click automatically an a href element using Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I would like a link to be automatically clicked after an event using vue.js
By using the related ref I get this error:

```
<a ref="goTo" href="#">Go To...</a>

 **Vue code**
this.$refs.goTo.click();
```

**Cannot read property 'click' of undefined**

Comment: Pls dont hide your question. It should be, `why is this.$refs[prop] undefined?`. Your provided code sample is insufficient to answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Is `this.$refs.goTo.click()` in `mounted` hook scope? If not, you'd better put it in mounted hook function.
Because when you execute the code, this dom element does't actually be rendered in tree, so you will get `undefined` from `this.$refs.goTo`. And sometimes it will be an array of instances, so you'd better check your refs before execute some functions.